Value function convex in probabilities?
I am interested in the convexity in $p$ of the value function
$$V(p,W)=max_{x,y,z} pf_1(x,y)+(1-p)f_2(x,z)$$
under the constraint
$$x+py+(1-p)z=W$$
where $0<p<1$ and where $f_1,f_2$ are strictly increasing and concave.
I would like to know whether it is true that $V$ is convex in $p$, or what conditions are required for convexity.
Any pointers appreciated.

what you have tried?

I have tried to start from $V(\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda) p_2,W)$ for $0<\lambda<1$ and it went nowhere. I have found results on the concavity of $V$ in $W$ but I could not apply the same mechanism.

it's pointwise maximize of linear functions, what's your conclusion..

@GBmath Thanks for the intuition. May I ask you to give me an indication of how to solve this formally. I get the intuition but I am not 100% convinced. I understand that if my problem was the maximization over (x,y,z) of a function linear in $p$, then the pointwise maximum argument means that the value function is convex in $p$. Here, I struggle to understand what additional issue the constraint in my problem poses. Because, the pointwise maximum might not work if as $p$ varies, the range of (x,y,z) I maximize over changes. I hope you can see what I mean. Thanks for your help...

@GBmath I have tried solving numerically for some specifications of $f_1,f_2$ and it seems that in general, there is neither concavity nor convexity. Still curious if you can help there.
